# useEffect continuously fires GET requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm learning React and trying to make a small project by myself for the first time, but I'm having trouble with `useEffect`.

I'm trying to autofill a form with information from my backend. I can get it to autofill, but it continuously sends GET requests. This is what I have:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .get('/admin/edit-product' + location.search)
        .then((res) => {
          const updatedControls = {
            ...controlsState,
            title: {
              ...controlsState.title,
              value: res.data.title,
            },
            image: {
              ...controlsState.image,
              value: res.data.image,
            },
            price: {
              ...controlsState.price,
              value: res.data.price,
            },
            description: {
              ...controlsState.description,
              value: res.data.description,
            },
          };
          setControlsState(updatedControls);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, [controlsState, location.search]);
```

I thought that the dependency array was supposed to stop it from running continuously, but I guess I'm missing something else.

Not sure if it's needed, but this is what my original state looks like:

```js
  const [controlsState, setControlsState] = useState({
    title: {
      elementType: 'input',
      elementConfig: {
        type: 'text',
      },
      label: 'Product Title: ',
      value: '',
    },
    image: {
      elementType: 'input',
      elementConfig: {
        type: 'url',
      },
      label: 'Image URL: ',
      value: '',
    },
    price: {
      elementType: 'input',
      elementConfig: {
        type: 'number',
      },
      label: 'Price: ',
      value: '',
    },
    description: {
      elementType: 'textarea',
      elementConfig: {
        name: 'description',
        htmlFor: 'description',
      },
      label: 'Description: ',
      value: '',
    },
  });
```

and `location` is from react-router-dom `useLocation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have given controlsState as a dependency for useEffect. But inside your useEffect you are using setControlsState which changes the value of controlsState. And since you have given controlsState as a dependency, useEffect will occur everytime any of its dependency changes. Hence it is repeatedly happening

If you want useEffect to run only once, give [] as second parameter:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    ...your code... 
}, [])
```

Comment: This worked (I'd tried this before, but it didn't work then for some reason), but now I have a warning in the console saying: "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'controlsState' and 'location.search'. Either include them or remove the dependency array". Is this safe to ignore?

Comment: If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

Comment: You might ignore warnings